# jQuery - How to select tablerow element using custom attribute value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some HTML similar to this, where a custom attribute value has been programmatically applied to rows in a table:

```
<table>
    <tr RowID="123">
        <%-- elements in row --%>
    </tr>
    <tr RowID="457">
        <%-- elements in row --%>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using jQuery, how can I select a row based on a particular RowID value so that I can show/hide that row?

I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
$("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']").show();
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/We2cL/, but you should avoid custom attributes anyway. At least use HTML 5 `data-*` attributes.

Comment: OK, I've just realised the problem was in my code which determined the rowID, and not in the selector, doh! Thanks for the help anyway guys!

Comment: Oh, and I'll look into using data-* attributes instead of custom, thanks ...

Answer (score 4):

What you have works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/e94W2/1

Is your coding inside a `$(document).ready(function() { })` block like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowID = 123;
    $('tr').hide();
    $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']").show();
});
```

If not it probably cant find the tablerow as it hasnt been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pagination in youre table mightbe that row is not on current page, because if row is loaded, you're code is OK.